# Make Highcharts tooltip show info for closest point to the left (i.e. not change at midpoint)

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Between two points on a line, if you move the cursor to the right of the midpoint, it will show the tooltip for the right point. Is there a way to keep the tooltip focused on the closest tooltip to the *left*? I find this more intuitive for my stepchart so that the tooltip displays the info for the current step being moused over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunaltey it is not possible, but you can try to replace line chart with, scatter series and setting lineWidth as 2.

```
plotOptions:{
                series:{
                    lineWidth:2
                }
            },
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/JG83j/